# java rs.getString() Error "Column Index out of range, 5 > 4"

Tags: java

I'm receiving this error : "Column Index out of range, 5 > 4" when I try to print my query.

I know that the error is because I'm trying to get more values that my tables has.... but in my case I trying to do a method which will be called from different query, thats mean that the value rage of each table could be different...

**This is the code:**

```
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;

 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

 public class TableCreator {
 String Query;
 ResultSet rs1;

 String string, string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6, string7,string8,string9;
 int numecolumns;


public TableCreator(String Query, String string, String string1, String string2, String string3, String string4, String string5, String string6, String string7,String string8,String string9){
    this.Query = Query;
    this.string = string;
    this.string1 = string1;
    this.string2 = string2;
    this.string3 = string3;
    this.string4 = string4;
    this.string5 = string5;
    this.string6 = string6;
    this.string7 = string7;
    this.string8 = string8;
    this.string9 = string9;

}

 public void Table(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException  {

    PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
    res.setContentType("text/html");

try
{

    CallDB query = new CallDB(Query);
    query.connectDB();
    rs1 = query.connectDB();

    pw.println(string+ "<br>");
    pw.println("<table><tr>");
    pw.println("<td><b>"+string+"</b></td>");
    pw.println("<td><b>"+string1+"</b></td>");
    pw.println("<td><b>"+string2+"</b></td>");
    pw.println("<td><b>"+string3+"</b></td>");
    pw.println("<td><b>"+string4+"</b></td>");
    pw.println("<td><b>"+string5+"</b></td>");


    while (rs1.next()){ 

        String string1 = rs1.getString(1);
        String string2 = rs1.getString(2); 
        String string3 = rs1.getString(3);
        String string4 = rs1.getString(4);
        String string5 = rs1.getString(5);


        pw.println("<tr>");
        pw.println("<td>"+string1+"</td>");
        pw.println("<td>"+string2+"</td>");
        pw.println("<td>"+string3+"</td>");
        pw.println("<td>"+string4+"</td>");
        pw.println("<td>"+string5+"</td>");

        pw.println("</tr>");
          } 
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
   }
 }
```

It is working fine if the table has at least the same number of columns but if it's least, I receive the error.
There is any way to break the **while** execution when the column doesn't exist?

thanks in advance

Comment: use `String... parameters` and iterate that, not param1, param2, param3 etc. A lot cleaner. Or just use a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`ResultSet.getMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29) to get the `ResultSet`'s metadata. That contains a [`ResultSetMetaData.getColumnCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnCount%28%29) method that tells you how many columns the `ResultSet` has.

Comment: Hi Chris, yes, you're right. But when I call the "ResultSet.getMetaData" and asign it to a variable, when I try to execute a "For" it doesn't print my tabe it's printin a value fro each line:

Comment: Doing something like this:

Comment: `ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs1.getMetaData();
int columns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
  
while (rs1.next()){
  for(int x = 1; x <= columns; x++ ){
   String pp = rs1.getString(x);
   pw.println("<tr>");
   pw.println("<td>"+pp+"</td>");
   pw.println("</tr>");`

Comment: @Sallyerik That is because your `<tr>` and `</tr>` are being printed from the wrong place. Try placing those _outside_ of the inner loop.

Comment: @Sallyerik Yay! I'm glad to hear it works. If you can, please click the green tick on my answer...I've already hit my rep cap, so the only way I can get any rep is by getting accepted answers. :-)